# How do i get my keycode to focus the element?

Tags: javascript

If i leave it without a keycode it will work with every key but i'm trying to add the "/" key which is keycode "191" and now i can't get it to work. I've even tried using the preventDefault after it and still nothing. How do i properly write it to make it work? Yes i also have the keypress in my input line as well, it's not the problem.

```
 function setFocusToTextBox(field, event) {
if (event.keyCode === 191) {
    document.getElementById("order_number").focus();
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.chip_insert.chip_number.focus();">

<center>
<h1>Jeffers HomeAgain Microchip Entry</h1>


<form name="chip_insert"  id="chip_insert" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" onkeydown="setFocusToTextBox(field, event)">
Order Number: <input tabindex="1" maxlength="12" type="text" name="order_number"  id="order_number"  value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  required="required"onkeydown="return tabOnEnter(this,event)" onfocus="this.focus();this.select()" /><br /><br />
Tag Number: <input tabindex="2" maxlength="15" type="text" name="chip_number" id="chip_number" required="required" /><br /><br />
<input tabindex="7" type="submit" />
</center>
</form>

<br />

<!--End body content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(event.kecode);` inside the function when pressing the **/-key**, what do you get in console?

Comment: Not all browsers support `event.keyCode`

Comment: It's `keyCode`, not `keycode`.

Comment: Have you tried `keyCode` not `keycode`, case matters

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: Here's how you'd do that -> **http://jsfiddle.net/n5cvmtxn/**

Comment: You need a capital C in `keycode`, that's all.

Comment: I'm starting to think Internet Explorer is the cause because none of these suggestions still work.  Is there a way to do it other then event.KeyCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', keydownCallback);

function keydownCallback(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 191) {
    setTimeout(setFocusToTextBox); // setTimeout prevents insertion of slash
  }
}

function setFocusToTextBox() {
  document.getElementById("order_number").focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="order_number" placeholder="Press / and I will be focused" size="60">
```

1. Press Run Code Snippet
2. Click somewhere on the area around the input
3. Press / and the input will be focused.

Comment: the "/" still inserted but i added this to the next input line so it just highlights the "/" and can be over-written, problem avoided. onfocus="this.focus();this.select()"

Answer (score 0):

The working of your snippet is also depends on the event you call from , try to call your function on keydown.

Below is your working code :

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) { 

if (e.keyCode === 191)

 alert('Correct');

else

 alert('wrong');

});
```

**keyCode may vary for different key events.**

Comment: i use this in my input line: onkeypress="setFocusToTextBox(field, event)"

Comment: so use onkeydown in place of onkeypress with code 191 for  ' / ' .

Comment: Please provide your whole code and from where you call this function ?? so its easy to find out the error. @chrisbahr

Comment: still nothing, i've tested the key for the right code and also the script works without the keyCode but then it does all keys.  Still now sure what else to try.  I also have one in my script that tabs on enter and it's a keycode but it works fine.

Comment: ok, i just updated my code up top. It starts from my previous code, everything above it is my php and tab to enter script.

Comment: what is "field" in parameter ?? check your console for errors .and try replace it to' onkeydown="return setFocusToTextBox(this, event)" '